# Low Energy Nuclear Reactions

Tags: nuclear

I was interested in knowing if Low Energy Nuclear Reactions are practical or just mythical. What is the current stance of the scientific society about their feasibility?

Comment: If they are trying to sell you free energy, it is nonsense. There are some interesting, but known, nuclear reactions but they are not particularly practical for energy production.

Answer (score 3):

The stance is currently an even mix of hogwash conspiracy theories, pseudoscience and scams.

Even if the field had merit - which it most likely doesn't, the number of anti-scientific "papers" on the subject has ruined it for a long time.